# Safe rounding of CCA during battery load testing

Tags: battery, diagnostics

How do you determine the safe amp load of a battery tester?

I am looking at testing a battery on a 2012 Mazda 3 sport which has a Mazda factory battery 75D23L (52).

The service manual states in the testing procedure that the Battery load test current should be **195 A**.

I have a budget load tester which does increments of 100 A. It states in the operating instructions: **"Round the battery number down to the nearest 100"**.

Now my gut says 195A is close enough to 200A, but what if...

If I drop the 100A, then the test seems like it would be no good. It would only be testing half the draw and may falsely pass.

200A is only about 2.6% higher than 195A. Would 3% over be too much?

Comment: Are you trying to diagnose a problem?  I frankly wouldn't bother with a load test if there are no indications (slow cranking, etc).  Cheap load testors are simply not that accurate.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could link the tester you’re using... without that information it’s hard to give a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that will be fine. Don't know what type of tester you have. If after the test it will give you a rating or just a pass/fail. But if its the original battery you may be at the end of its life. Especially if it's starting to give you problems.